# Getting Selected Item From a Dropdown MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created a dropdown like this:

```
 <%= Html.DropDownList("Nick") %>
```

When a user selects an item I wanna send the text of the item back to a controller Action. I am guessin I add the same name of the the get controller with an [HTTPPOST] attribute, but how do I pass the selected item text into the controller?

I want this 2 happen in 2 scenerios 
-When a user selects an item
-Add a button to the html (im not sure the best way??) and when a user clicks the button

the dropdowns selected text is sent.

I am populating the dropdown from ViewData["items"] i populated in the controller.

Comment: right after the user selects an item? or when the user clicks submit? that's in the drop down?

Comment: Can you show me an example of both Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a form. You need to populate the drop down. And if you want the form to be sent as soon as the item is selected, you need half a line of javascript.

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
  <%: Html.DropDownList("nick",
        new SelectList[] { new[] { "hello", "world", "wazza" } }, 
        new { @onchange = "this.form.submit()" })%>
<% } %>
```

You may also want your controller to receive a value rather than the text in the list option. See the [SelectList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx) for more details.

Comment: This isnt working for me there its saying there is no overload for those parameters...I am populating the cropdown from ViewData["items"]

Comment: I have it working, but its returning the value and not the text. How do I return the text?

Answer (score 0):

Have your form submit to this action.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string nick)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Comment: How does the selectItem_Change event like in web forms get triggered?

Comment: @Nick, it doesn't. There is no concept of server side event handlers in MVC. If you need to do something after a user selects an item, then you need to use javascript. Edit your question to tell us what you want to happen.